# Getting an error while staring a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring boot application which uses elasticsearch for persistence. When I start the application. I get this error

```
2019-03-10 13:40:34.969 ERROR 6442 --- [  restartedMain] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{dwDmvmEpTaGofz678sLuFw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}, {#transport#-2}{3MRMgg73T1eBHFiozEJABw}{192.168.1.6}{192.168.1.6:9300}]
2019-03-10 13:40:35.176 DEBUG 6442 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.lociscore.services.LociScoreService  : --LociScoreService Intialized------
```

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE.

Here is the my configuration

server.port=29090
server.address=localhost
server.ssl.enabled=false

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true

spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300,192.168.1.6:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name= "elasticsearch"
spring.es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors = false
```

I'm running Elastic search using docker. The command which I have used to start ES is as follows

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e "cluster.name=loci-score" -d --name thesiselasticsearch -d --network mynetwork docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.3
```

I can't figure out why the error is happening. From the docs which I have read for Spring Data ElasticSearch, the versions which I'm using are compatible.